# regular expression to match the first occureance of an underscore (_) in R

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I try to transpose a dataframe from wide to long format. I use the function `pivot_longer` from the tidyr package. My column names have the following format:

```
H198_text
K177_test
P100_find_g9
K077_tmk_g9
```

In long format, the dataframe should have a column "Item" containing "H198", "K177", "P100", etc. "text", "test", "find_g9" should become the other columns. For separating the column names I need a regular expression to match the first underscore (e.g.: `for P100_find_g9`, my result should be the match of the first underscore (P100 **_** find_g9)). This is what the code for the functions looks like:

```
library(tidyr)

data_long = data %>% pivot_longer(
  cols = !Participant, 
  names_to = c('Item', '.value'), 
  names_sep = <regex>
)
```

I probably need to use `?` for lazy matching, but I did not manage to find a way on my own.

I tried different expressions with grouping, `^`, `?`, `(_?)`. I am working in R but tried all the commands in regex101.com.

Comment: Do you want to know whether there is an underscore in the string? What should the result look like

Comment: The regular expression to do that is — *literally!* — `_`. That’s it.

Comment: You would want to use `names_pattern` instead to use a `regex` expression to capture each group: `pivot_longer(cols = !Participant, names_to = c('Item', '.value'), names_pattern = "([^_]+)_(.*)")` specifying the two groups to match. Alternatively, you might be able to use `names_sep` to break on the 5th position, i.e. `pivot_longer(cols = !Participant, names_to = c('Item', '.value'), names_sep = 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with

```r
df <- structure(list(Participant = "A", H198_text = 1L, K177_test = 1L, P100_find_g9 = 1L, K077_tmk_g9 = 1L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
df
#   Participant H198_text K177_test P100_find_g9 K077_tmk_g9
# 1           A         1         1            1           1
```

We can do

```r
pivot_longer(df,
  -Participant, names_pattern = "([^_]+)_(.*)",
  names_to = c("Item", ".value"))
# # A tibble: 4 × 6
#   Participant Item   text  test find_g9 tmk_g9
#   <chr>       <chr> <int> <int>   <int>  <int>
# 1 A           H198      1    NA      NA     NA
# 2 A           K177     NA     1      NA     NA
# 3 A           P100     NA    NA       1     NA
# 4 A           K077     NA    NA      NA      1
```